# Update observable when array in NGRX store changes

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a need to update an observable when an arry kept in the NGRX store changes. Currently, I use a selector to select the array list, but I'm not sure if this is very efficient code, since I want it to call the next function only any time the selector returns a different array object.

This is my code:

```
 this.store.select<any[]>(getConnections(Id))
                .takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(connections => {
                    this.selectDataStream.next(connections);
                });
```

Selector:

```
export const getConnections = (id) => createSelector(selectFinderResults, entities => {
    return entities[id].connections;
});
```

Reducer:

```
 case LOAD_INTEGRATOR_CONNECTIONS_SUCCESS: {
          let payload = (action as LoadConnectionsSuccessAction).payload;
          let integratorId = (action as LoadConnectionsSuccessAction).integratorId;

          if (payload) {

              const integratorModel = state.connectorresults[integratorId];

              const updatedstate = {
                  ...state,
                  connectorresults: {
                      ...state.connectorresults,
                      [integratorId]: {
                          ...integratorModel,
                          connections: payload
                      }
                  },
                  searchconnectorresults: {
                      ...state.searchconnectorresults,
                      [integratorId]: {
                          ...integratorModel,
                          connections: payload
                      }
                  }
              };

              return {
                  ...updatedstate
              };
          }


      }
```

Is this the best way to trigger the next function on the Subject when the connections list changes? I want it to trigger multiple times,  but only when the list changes but it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Could you add the code for getConnections(Id)?

Comment: @DavidSherman Code is added

Comment: This really depends on how you update your state. Please add code of relevant reducer that changes this part of state.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov See reducer code. The array is updated with a new list when it's result is received.

Comment: I see you are directly assigning payload to connections, if payload is the same array as the existing value on that object the selector will not emit because it is reffering to the same array. If this is applicable try this:

`{ ...integratorModel, connections: [...payload] }`